# Given an operator $ * $ and it's inverse $ \setminus $ when does $ x \setminus y = x * \left( 0 \setminus y \right) $?

Tags: group-theory, operator-theory

Given a groupoid $ \left( M, * \right) $ with an neutral element $0$ and $\setminus$ being an inverse operator of $*$, what are the groupoid's properties for this predicate to be true?

$$ \forall x, y \in M: x \setminus y = x * \left( 0 \setminus y \right) $$

It works for $\left(\mathbb{Z},+\right)$ and $\left(\mathbb{R},\cdot\right)$ but I didn't find any specific rule.

Comment: How do you define "inverse operator"?

Comment: Do you have in mind any particular axioms/properties that you want your operators to satisfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that "$\setminus$ is an inverse operator of $*$" means that $(x*y)\setminus y=(x\setminus y)*y=x$ for all $x,y$. Then

$$ x*(0\setminus y)\stackrel I=((x*(0\setminus y))*y)\setminus y\stackrel A=(x*((0\setminus y)*y))\setminus y\stackrel I=(x*0)\setminus y\stackrel N=x\setminus y$$

by applying $I$ the inverse property, $A$ associativity, and $N$ the property of the neutral element.